# LABVIEW:SMTP cannot connect

Tags: smtp, gmail, client, send, labview

I want to send an email from LabVIEW with an attachment, but I don't know what's the problem.
Has Google removed the option to allow less secure apps to send an email? Is any other way to do it?

[image]

I tried to change the port and use Outlook but it's not working neither.

Answer (score 0):

It might have problem with parsing IP address. Try to remove space before port number, and specify it in one string, without spaces, like this:

*smtp.gmail.com:587*

Comment: i tried it but another error appeared "incorect user or password' even though they are correct

Comment: Well, it's already different problem then. My answer is related to "network address is ill-formed" error... Nevertheless, test it like this: copy-paste e-mail and password without modifications, and try to login to gmail.com. Do not type it, but copy-paste to really make sure that credentials are correct in the VI.

Comment: i tried to copy paste but another   error has occurred  while sending data on the network.

Comment: Just to be clear: you can't use your standard password for this. You need to generate a separate app password and use that (see [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)).    If that's not the issue, then you need to provide the details of exactly what the error is and where it occurs, as well as what your current code looks like.

Comment: i tried to use app password and i have this error ''LabVIEW: (Hex 0x58BF9) An error occurred while sending data on the network.''

Comment: @noorb, check this thread - https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Error-363513-Occurred-when-using-smtp-to-send-email/m-p/3661903#M1029136, and play around with TLS ON/OFF setting.